# Problema con evento .click

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un botón, que oculte y muestre el mismo elemento al hacer click, la idea que pensé fue cambiarle el `id` al <kbd>boton</kbd>, es decir, de `id = "mostrar"` a `id = "oculto"` y viceversa.

Al ocultarlo, funciona correctamente, el problema es cuando lo voy a mostrar, ya que luego de ocultarlo, y volver a presionar el botón, no muestra nada.

- **HTML:**

```html
<div id="navbar">
       elemento
</div>


<button type="button" id="mostrar">
    Presionar
</button>
```

- **JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$("#mostrar").click(function() {
    $("#navbar").animate({
        left: '-100%',
        opacity: '0.5',
    }, 1500);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#navbar").hide();
        $("#mostrar").attr("id", "oculto");
    }, 200);

});

$("#oculto").click(function() {
    $("#navbar").animate({
        left: '0',
        opacity: '1',
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#mostrar").show();
        $("#oculto").attr("id", "mostrar");
    }, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este evento `$("#oculto").click` es creado antes de que exista dicho elemento (seleccionado de esa manera), `.on` solucionaría ese problema, de cualquier manera sería mas fácil usando `.toggle()` que recibe *n* funciones y las intercambia cada vez, sin parámetros solo oculta y muestra:

```js
$("#boton").click(function() {
  $("#navbar").toggle(
    function() {
      $("#navbar").animate({
        opacity: '0.5',
      }, 2000);
    },

    function() {
      $("#navbar").animate({
        opacity: '1',
      }, 2000);
    }


  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  elemento
</div>
<button type="button" id="boton">
  Presionar
</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar el método [.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) de jQuery para ocultar y mostrar el div.

```js
$('#mostrar').click(function(){
  $('#navbar').toggle();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
       elemento
</div>


<button type="button" id="mostrar">
    Ocultar/Mostrar
</button>
```